# SSRS calculate percentage of column based on row total

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression

I have a data set which looks like this

```
+------------+-----------------------------+
| user_name  |             role            |
+------------+-----------------------------+
| User A     |  Admin, System              |
| User B     |  Editor, Power User, System |
+------------+-----------------------------+
```

I would like to calculate the total of each column (A,B) as a percentage  of the Row total to look like

```
+-------+-----+-----+-------+
| Month |  A  |  B  | TOTAL |
+-------+-----+-----+-------+
| Jan   | 90% | 10% | 100%  |
| Feb   | 90% | 10% | 100%  |
| Mar   | 75% | 25% | 100%  |
+-------+-----+-----+-------+
```

I have tried a Table and Matrix cant seem to get either to work:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your % value expression should be something like:

```
=Sum(Fields!Income.Value) / Sum(Fields!Income.Value, "RowGroupName")
```

Where `RowGroupName` is the name of your defined `Month` row group, as you may notice with the example given.

This applies the total `Income` for a particular `Fee_To` / `Month` group to all `Fee_To`  total `Income` values in that `Month` group.

Comment: Hi @Ian thank you for this. seems to work fine until you try it twice. I have one column for Orders and one for Income. I get an error _"The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox153’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset."_

Comment: Made a work around. Duplicated the dataset and set it up again.

Comment: Please don't use the word "obviously".  I'm actually trying to get that very part to work on my report: putting the correct string value in to get the intended behavior.  What is obvious to an expert is not obvious to a new person.

Comment: I edited the word "obviously" out and tried to convey a similar meaning. I agree with comment by user38858.