How to calculate percentage under each group in SSRS?
I want to calculate the percentage for paper and online group. The total should be 100%
I have one column group and row group. The column group has title with expression like
=IIF(Fields!SOURCE.Value = "Fax", "Paper Percentage", IIF(Fields!SOURCE.Value = "Web", "Online Percentage", ""))

My current results showing either 100% or 1 for both.(like below)

I have tried using below expression but both does not working as I said either showing 1 or 100%
=CountDistinct(Fields!SOURCE.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!SOURCE.Value,"SOURCE1")

=IIF(Fields!SOURCE.Value = "Fax", 
     Format(Sum(IIF(Fields!SOURCE.Value = "Fax", 1, 0)) / Sum(Count(Fields!SOURCE.Value)) * 100, "N2") & "%",
     IIF(Fields!SOURCE.Value = "Web",
         Format(Sum(IIF(Fields!SOURCE.Value = "Web", 1, 0)) / Sum(Count(Fields!SOURCE.Value)) * 100, "N2") & "%",
         ""))

How do I calculate both percentage based on which group they belongs to?
Please let me know if I need to add more details.
Thanks so much!

I don't imagine the "CountDistinct" is going to give you what you are after, if "SOURCE" just contains either "Fax" or "Web" (or potentially something else).  You're close, though - you'll likely want to use "Sum", getting the sum at the row/column intersection, divided into the sum total of the corresponding row.  These couple of pages give you some pointers.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205659/ssrs-calculate-percentage-of-column-based-on-row-total   https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/ssrs-percentage-over-main-rows-in-matrix-colum

@Craig Hey Thanks for you reply. But it throws me an error. Here is my expression: =SUM(Fields!SOURCE.Value) / SUM(Fields!SOURCE.Value,"SOURCE1")
is this something has to do with my alias? because my Fax is promoted as Paper and Web promoted as online.

Actually, you probably want to use COUNT(Fields!SOURCE.Value).  I assume the actual GROUP BY on your column group is "SOURCE"?  What, actually, is "SOURCE1" referring to?  In the case of the % result that you want, you should be referring to the Name/ID of the row group.  If "SOURCE1" is your actual dataset (and not the specific row group), then you will get the total across the entire set of data, not the month-by-month total

For debugging purposes, I would put two extra fields in your column - one with COUNT(Fields!SOURCE.Value), and the other with COUNT(Fields!SOURCE.Value, ""), to confirm the actual values that are coming from each of those expressions

If you don't get anywhere, share a sample of the data (as it appears in the result of your dataset query and as text please) so I can try to reproduce it. Also show the report design and row/column groups.

If you are simply counting rows (so you actually have 48307 rows in your dataset for this example), then you should just be able to do the following...
=COUNT(Fields!SOURCE.Value) / COUNT(Fields!SOURCE.Value,"myMonthRowGroup")

Where myMonthRowGroup is the name of the row group (not the column group). All the above does is
COUNT(Fields!SOURCE.Value) gets the number of rows in the current scope (i.e. in the current row and column group)
COUNT(Fields!SOURCE.Value,"myMonthRowGroup") gets the number of rows in the specified scope, in the case the entire row for Mar-24
